# Do animals have greater tendency to care for their opposite sex siblings due to mate competition among same sex siblings?

Tags: evolution, evolutionary-game-theory

According to the gene-centered view of evolution, siblings have p=1/2 relatedness, thus having greater altruism between them than cousins or unrelated animals.

For species with a conventional sex binary, how does sibling sex relate to altruism? My idea is that siblings of opposite sex show greater altruism than siblings of same sex, since siblings of same sex have more to compete over. Namely, same sex siblings compete for the same pool of mates. Is this something known to be true in studies of species altruism?